# Sessionize time sequence data in SQL

Tags: sql, group-by, window

I have some time sequence data in SQL. I am attempting to "sessionize" this data. New sessions occur when a break larger than n time units occurs.

Input in CSV form:

```
Time, TimeDiffFromLast
0,0
1,1
2,1
17,15
18,1
19,1
32,13
33,1
34,1
```

For this example, a new session should be created if the time difference from the last row is greater than n=10 time units.

Desired output in CSV form:

```
Time, TimeDiffFromLast, SessionLabel
0,0,a
1,1,a
2,1,a
17,15,b
18,1,b
19,1,b
32,13,c
33,1,c
34,1,c
```

Is there any way to do this in SQL in general? Or it is not possible and I need to sequentially iterate over the data?

Comment: should the session labels be alphabets? or can they be numbers as well?

Comment: Any unique label would be fine for the SessionLabel field. Int for instance would probably be ideal in my case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `case` expression to specify the start of a group when the diff > 10. Then use a running sum to classify session labels.

```
select time,diff_from_last,sum(col) over(order by time) as session_label
from (
select time, time-lag(time,1,time) over(order by time) as diff_from_last,
case when time-lag(time,1,time) over(order by time) > 10 then 1 else 0 end as col
from tbl
) t
```

This assumes the dbms you are using supports window functions.

Comment: I am in Apache Spark SQL. I was surprised that your above query worked exactly as above. I expected some of the syntax to be missing. Nice work with the lag and case functionality. I will read up on those bits.